# 4TB GPT drive formated in Windows shows up as 2TB in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, gpt

I have a 4 TB drive connected to a Dell H200 controller. The drive was formatted in Windows using GPT and correctly shows 4TB in Windows.

The same drive in the same computer booted up in linux (Ubuntu 16.04) is not fully recognized as having 4 TB.

Running `gdisk /dev/sdb -l` results in

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
3519068194 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
```

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 4294967295 sectors, 2.0 TiB
```

```
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): F8EA0B25-8D84-4BBB-88EB-BA90615C5318
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 4294967261
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              34          262177   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   2          264192      7814035455   3.6 TiB     0700  Basic data partition
```

Notice the "2.0 TiB" in bold above

I also can't mount any of it. Mounting /dev/sdb1 results in a "mount: wrong fs type..." error and mounting /dev/sdb2 results in

```
mount: special device /dev/sdb2 does not exist
```

At first I thought it was a firmware issue with the H200 controller, but that doesn't explain why it works in Windows and not Linux, and why it can't be mounted. How can I get Linux to recognize the drive? Do I need to reformat the drive using Linux? How can I ensure either operating system can see the drive properly in the future?

**UPDATE:**

Well, I feel a little silly now. It turns out that it was an issue with the H200 controller firmware all along.

I first tried updating the H200 controller firmware and `gdisk` now properly returns:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 7814037168 sectors, 3.6 TiB
```

and /dev/sdb2 mounts without issue. What I'm now trying to understand is why the disk was reading properly in Windows (7) and not in Linux with outdated H200 firmware.

Comment: That's super bizarre. It sees that it's GPT, so it shouldn't have the MBR disk-size limit (512 B/sector * 2^32 addressable sectors). It sees the partition size correctly (3.6TB is about right after converting from base10 TB). You're running a recent kernel, so it's probably not just outdated hardware support...

Comment: Do a **uname -r** just to make sure your kernel is new enough.  I could assume things, but I have learn how dangerous that is.  I don't know if it is possible, but I would kill the protective MBR non-sense.

Comment: @SkyNT: Can you tell me what H200 firmware version you had been using, and what update fixed the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The situation seems to me clear, less clear is why it has occurred. Your output states:

```
Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by 3519068194 blocks!
```

GPT has two partition tables, a primary one located at the beginning of the disk, and a second (or backup) one located in the last 33 sectors (16K) of the disk, see [the ever helpful Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table) on this.

It often occurs that people do not leave room for the backup PT, when manually partitioning a disk, which leads to complaints by disk utilities about the lack of a secondary partition table, and a warning to resize the last partition by shrinking it by 33 sectors.

You have precisely the same case, except your backup PT comes 3.5x10^9 sectors (\approx 1.8TB) too soon. In other words, the `gdisk` utility sees a misplaced backup PT and thinks this is the end of the disk. Hence the smaller disk size (2TiB instead of your 4TB), and the impossibility to mount a partition which extends far beyond the disk (presumed) edge.

How did this come about? I can only speculate, but it is rather peculiar that the backup PT appears at the end of *precisely* 2TiB, the theoretical upper limit (see [the rightmost box on this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table)) for FAT32 file systems (with 512B sectors). The code of the file system from the output of `gdisk`, `0x0700`, is not very informative: according to [Rod Smith's book](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html),

> Windows uses a single GUID code for all its data partitions, be they FAT or NTFS

which is essentially the code 0x0700. Hence I cannot know whether it is FAT32 or NTFS, but if it were FAT32 we could understand the conundrum you find yourself in. More troublesome are the presence of a partition (`sdb2`) larger than the available disk,

```
... last usable sector is 4294967261
```

while the end sector of `sdb2` is 7814035455, and the error message

```
 mount: special device /dev/sdb2 does not exist
```

Most likely, we are seeing the result of several attempts at partitioning, with some errors/bugs/whatchamacallit.

Also, `gdisk` is adamant about your choices:

```
    You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
```

Either option implies data loss. I have no idea what is on your disk, whether it is brand new or full of long-cherished personal data, so I do not know precisely what to suggest. Of course, backing everything up (from Windows), then reformatting the disk (in Linux), and trying out the disk on Windows before actually storing anything on it sounds like a reasonable course of action. Also, I suggest you choose a file system like NTFS, which has no limitation of the disk size (or at least, none that is relevant to a 4TiB disk), again [see this on the rightmost box of this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS).

Comment: What's that GUID? I thought GUID on GPT is a 16-byte code. MBR partition type is 1 byte only and 0x07 is for NTFS but FAT32 LBA is 0x0C, along with many other values for FAT12, FAT16...

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You are right on all counts, but, according to Rod Smith's book,   Windows uses a single GUID code for all its data partitions, be they FAT or NTFS. Thus, in this case several different MBR codes are all translated into a single GPT GUID code. GPT fdisk uses, somewhat arbitrarily, the 0x0700 code (or more precisely, EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7) for all of these.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Thanks for your answer. Please see my update; I've solved my problem by simply updating the H200 controller drivers. I'm still left a little confused, however. Do you have any idea why firmware would cause one OS to not see the drive properly, while another OS might?

Comment: My ***guess*** is that the OSes are using different low-level calls to determine the disk size. Presumably the disk controller was developed and tested primarily with Windows, so the firmware flaw that caused problems with Linux was not discovered until after the product shipped.